# Extracting multiple fields from resume with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to process a lot resume in Python. An example of a resume may look like the below. Unfortunately, each resume may not use the same format. Is there a good way to do this besides using regex to extract certain fields from the resume (assuming I converted all of them into plain text) with python?

```
Name: Someone
Tel: xxx-xxxxxxx
Add: 123 Some Street
Email: Someone@gmail.com

Objective/Goal
To obtain a position in...

Education
2004 - 2006: University of XYZ


Work Experience
2006 - 2008: Programmer

Skills
Programming skills: Python, ..
```

Let's say I am only interested to extract a few fields in there, how can I get all the text between the field name and the next field? For example I just want to get the name and work experience field, it should return the following.

```
NameField = 'Someone'
WorkExpField = '2006 - 2008: Programmer...'
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, each resume may not use the same format" that makes this pretty complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My "I'm going to try this, but too lazy to make pretty" approach for different format resumes. I'm willing to test it out on different resume formats.
Additional advice/opinions welcome!

```
import string

class Resume():
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filepath = filename
        self.load()
        self.parse()

    def load(self):
        with open(self.filepath,'rb') as f:
            self.content = f.read().splitlines()

    def checkLine(self,word,value, content, line):
        if word in content.lower():
            value = self.addValue(value,line)
        return value

    def addValue(self,value,line):
        value[line] = value.get(line,0) + 1
        return value

    def dict_List(self,dict_, content):
        new = [(key,value) for key,value in dict_.items() if dict_[key] == max(dict_.values())]
        return [(x[0],content[x[0]]) for x in sorted(new)]

    def get_name(self):
        names = []
        for each in self.name:
            if each[0] not in self.headings:
                each = each[1].replace('Name',"")
                if each[0] not in string.letters:
                    each = each[1:]
                names.append(each.strip())
            else:
                index = self.headings[self.headings.index(each[0])+1]
                names.append("\n".join(self.content[each[0]+1:index]))
        if len(names) == 1:
            return names[0]
        else:
            return names

    def get_work(self):
        experience = []
        for each in self.work:
            index = self.headings[self.headings.index(each[0])+1]
            experience.append("\n".join(self.content[each[0]+1:index]))
        if len(experience) == 1:
            return experience[0]
        else:
            return epxerience

    def parse(self):
        name = dict()
        work_experience = dict()
        isHeading = dict()
        for line_num in range(len(self.content)):
            for checkName in ["name",":"]:
                name.update(self.checkLine(checkName,name,self.content[line_num], line_num))
            for checkWork in ["work","experience"]:
                work_experience.update(self.checkLine(checkWork,work_experience, self.content[line_num],line_num))
            if line_num != len(self.content) - 1:
                if len(self.content[line_num + 1]) > len(self.content[line_num]):
                    isHeading.update(self.addValue(isHeading,line_num))
            if line_num > 0:
                if self.content[line_num - 1] == "":
                    isHeading.update(self.addValue(isHeading,line_num))
            if len(self.content[line_num]) == len(self.content[line_num].lstrip()):
                isHeading.update(self.addValue(isHeading,line_num))
            if self.content[line_num] == "":
                isHeading[line_num] = isHeading.get(line_num,0) - 1

        self.name = self.dict_List(name, self.content)
        self.work = self.dict_List(work_experience, self.content)
        self.headings = self.dict_List(isHeading, self.content)
        self.headings = [x[0] for x in self.headings]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    resume = Resume(filename = 'sampleresume.txt')
    print resume.get_name()
    print resume.get_work()
```

Yields:

```
Someone
2006 - 2008: Programmer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [regexp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)s.

They allow you to parse text.

An example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import re

prog = re.compile("\s*(Name|name|nick).*")
result = prog.match("Name: Bob Exampleson")

if result:
    print result.group(0)

result = prog.match("University: MIT")

if result:
    print result.group(0)
```

Depending on the different texts your candidates use, you will have to refine your searches.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't very useful if you don't have a well-defined format.